# SVD explaination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Can someone give me the right hint to understand understand [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esfpu.jpg) proof?

To be precise, I don't understand why "*Since any vector $v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the singular vectors plus a vector perpendicular to the $v_i$*".

Answer (score 0):

In the cited passage, $A$ is an $n\times d$ matrix of rank $r$, with $r$ non-zero singular values.  The $r$ vectors $v_i$ might not span the full $d$-dimensional space $\mathbb R^d $.  For instance, if $r<d$. The author is evidently covering that possibility.